# Swift Dynamic Framework error of Class is not a member of type of class SDKA.SDKA

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am new to creating Swift Framework and I am trying to create a new dynamic framework (B.xcframework) that also uses another dynamic framework (A.xcframework). What I have done so far is to add A.xcframework into B.xcframework and checked that it is shown under Frameworks and Libraries with "Do not Embled" and also shown under Link Binary with Libraries (Build Phases) as Required Status.

[image]

[image]

I also have a sample APP target within my framework to make sure that my B.xcframework builds and runs perfectly on it. However when I try to create and build a brand new App project and add in my B.xcframework, I encounter multiple errors of "ClassADelegate" is not a member type of class "A.A". Any idea what I have not done correctly or misconfigured? Do let me know if there is any other information I can provide on my end to give a clearer understanding of my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Where you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @Kireyin I saw this one solution that is by manually removing the additional "A." for all the system generated .private.swiftinterface and .swiftinterface. Tried it and it work perfectly but it's a weird solution having to manually remove the additional class reference since it's generated automatically xcodebuild archive.

Comment: Late response. I did the same, I now have a script that runs after archiving to remove those symbols for each `.private.swiftinterface`. 

Weird workaround indeed but it's working. I plan a rename of either the framework or the public class but that's a huge breaking change :/

Comment: All good, I am glad that it is working for you now at least :)

Answer (score 0):

Add -no-verify-emitted-module-interface to Other Swift Flags to your Build Settings if you are using SPM or Cocoapods.